# Want to access VPC value from different VPC cloud-formation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, devops, aws-cli

I've created different cloudformation template of VPC at different account. I want to access VPC value (Nacl, security Group, natGateway, vpcPeering) from different VPC to my current VPC cloudformation template(output not work for me)

Comment: Why would you want to retrieve VPC information from another account? Will it be referencing a **shared VPC**?

Comment: yes it is shared vpc now i want to access information of vpc by stack name

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. Normally, one CloudFormation template can refer to another by name or using import/export.

However, this **would not work if accessing a stack in another account** or another region.

You will need to pass this information into the template via the Parameters.

An alternative is to **create a Custom Resource**, which is an AWS Lambda function. With the right permissions, the Custom Resource in Account-A could retrieve information from a CloudFormation stack in Account-B, then return the values to the stack. These values could then be referenced in other parts of the template.

The Lambda function would need to **assume an IAM Role** in Account-B, where that Role has permission to query CloudFormation to obtain the values.

Comment: thanks john , if i have a vpc in smae region and same account the can i acces vpc value without output in my vpc cloudformation template

Comment: CloudFormation cannot reference existing resources unless they are provided as Parameters. The Custom Resource would be a way to obtain the information, but you will need to code this functionality.